# Origin of "s**t one's pants"

Tags: etymology, idioms

How did the expression *shit one's pants* appear? Why is the word *in* left out before *one's pants*?

Comment: *shit*, vt, vulgar : to defecate in

Answer (score 2):

Seems that it follows the same pattern as "wet one's pants" or "dirty one's pants" or the like. The first word in both of these is a transitive verb, so the one in your example is evidently being used in the same way.